# Cocoapods: Create a lib with contain Core Data. but don't get the Core Data entity

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, lib

I'm trying to create a lib with cocoapods. but I have a problem.
I have no prestige for the moment. If you want to help me, you can open the next image.
[A cocoapods lib of local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xsvl.png)

When I tried to use coredata, re-installed cocoapods. That project doesn't have coredata.xcdatamodeld file.
 I find this resolve func, but don't resolve this problem.
[This Error with use of undeclared type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUhBb.png)
It is passed when I build the project the coredata_bundle-target.
I hope someone to can help me. thank you very much.
[This bundle build result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkL4y.png)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am trying to be a better self. Thank you again! `translate from **https://translate.google.com**` Haha

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this problem.

```
s.source_files = 'MCLogin/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'

s.resources = 'MCLogin/Classes/**/*.{xcdatamodeld}'
```

**This .xcdatamodeld file should be placed in the ' resources ' file**

English is not good, hope you don't laugh at me!